# Exit the shell script from embedded python code

Tags: python, bash, shell, variables

I want to exit the shell script from the embedded python code. Below os.system() is not working and rest of the shell scripting code is still getting executed.

```
echo "this is shell code"
a=10
python << END
import os
print "this is python code"

if True:
        print "yes"
        print $a
        os.system("exit 1")
END
echo "I am out of python code"
```

Comment: Short answer: You can't do that.

Comment: You can't but google the shell command `set -e` for one way to have your shell exit if the python script (or anything else it calls) exits with a non-zero status.

Answer (score 0):

You have to exit the shell explicitly based on the result of the Python script.

```
echo "this is shell code"
a=10
python "$a" <<END || exit
print "this is python code"
if True:
    print "yes"
    print(sys.argv[1])
    sys.exit(1)
END
echo "I am out of python code"
```

In this example, where the Python code unconditionally exits with a status of 1, the final `echo` will not be reached, as the nonzero exit status will cause the shell command `exit` to run.